# Using transformToFragment in XML after replacing nodes from a second XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm loading two different XML files, both of which have an entity node. I'm taking this node in one and replacing it with the other. After this I'm using XSLTProcessor to apply an xsl stylesheet to it.

I know that using one of the files works and I can apply the stylesheet:

```
let xmlBase = loadXMLDoc('alerts_base.xml');
let newDoc = xsltAlertsProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlBase, ownerDocument);
```

But this way, when it's applying the stylesheet, some elements appear, but not any of the new entity elements.

```
let xmlBase = loadXMLDoc('alerts_base.xml');
let xmlExtra = loadXMLDoc('alerts_extra.xml');
xmlBase.querySelector('entity').replaceWith(xmlExtra.querySelector('entity'));
let newDoc = xsltAlertsProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlBase, ownerDocument);
```

When I console log xmlBase after the replaceWith, I can see the new nodes as they should be, but for some reason they're not being styled by the XSLTProcessor.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide minimal examples for the xml and xsl files,

Comment: It is not clear from the JavaScript code how the XML documents look and what the XSLT is supposed to "style" and where and why that fails, we really need to see minimal but complete samples of the both XMLs, the XSLT and the result of the XSLT transformation to tell. However, in general, if matching/transforming with XSLT fails, it is often due to namespaces being used in the XML input but not being properly declared and used in the XSLT:

Comment: Thank you, I knew that there was some problem with the namespace, but I thought I was able to get around that because I was copying child nodes and not the root not in the XML document where the namespace declaration was. After a bit of testing I was able to get it working, but I had to put a namespace with a prefix in my xsl file, and had to use that prefix for each and and every match and select throughout the document. Is there a way to declare the namespace to apply the for root and all children? I couldn't get it to work with just a base xmlns declaration in the stylesheet tag.

Comment: For whatever reason, the whole namespace thing has been extra confusing to wrap my head around.